# Spring Security 3.1 - LdapAuthenticationProvider + GrantedAuthoritiesMapper

Tags: spring, spring-security

I created an AuthoritiesMapper for DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator. Roles are being mapped correctly and working with intercept-url.

If I try to access the roles in the controller using getUserPrincipal(), I'm still getting the LDAP groups.

Had a look at the code in the populator and it should work.

Any idea what wrong or how it can be fixed? i need to show/hide parts of views depending on roles

```
/*************************************************************************************
 * Maps Spring Security GrantedAuthorities 
 * e.g. AD groups populated using LdapAuthoritiesPopulator mapped to fixed role names
 * as defined in a Map instance (e.g. populated from a property file)
 * 
 * Sample roleMap:
 * Key          Value
 * Group1       ROLE_USER
 * Group2       ROLE_ADMIN
 * Group3       ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER
 *************************************************************************************/
public class MapBasedGrantedAuthorityMapper implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {
    private Map<String,String> roleMap;
    private String stringSeparator = ",";
    private SimpleGrantedAuthority unknownAuthorithy = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_UNKNOWN");
    private boolean keepUnknownAuthorities = false;
    public MapBasedGrantedAuthorityMapper(Map<String,String> roleMap){
        this.roleMap = roleMap;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        String[] mappedValues; 
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mapped = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>(authorities.size());
        for (GrantedAuthority auth : authorities) {
            if (roleMap.containsKey(auth.getAuthority())) {
                mappedValues = StringUtils.split(roleMap.get(auth.getAuthority()),stringSeparator);
                for (String mappedValue: mappedValues) {                    
                    mapped.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(mappedValue)));
                }
            } else if (keepUnknownAuthorities){ 
                mapped.add(auth);
            } else if (unknownAuthorithy != null){
                mapped.add(unknownAuthorithy);
            }
        }       
        return mapped;
    }
             // getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around this..

in the views I can use this the spring security taglibs

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

and in the service layer I can use @Secured